# Random number loop

Tags: java, random

I'm making the connect 4 game in Java and in vs computer mode. The computer will play randomly. I wrote the code to select randomly the column. Computer does play randomly on a column but keep on playing on same column after.

How should I do to make it play randomly on any column whenever its computer's turn.
This is my simple code so far:

```
public static Random rnd = new Random();
public static final int row = Row - 1;
public static int col = rnd.nextInt(7);
```

What code should I write and I need the variable `col` for my next method of this class

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `nextInt` each time the computer plays, to regenerate a random number.

What you currently have will generate a random number for the column but you never update it. So for each new game, the computer will play only in the same "random" column.

Let's say you have a method `computerTurn()` that you calls each time it's the turn of the computer to play. So something like that.

```
void computerTurn(){
    int col = rnd.nextInt(7);
    placeInCol(compute, col);
}
```

Note that you will have to check that you can play in the column. So the best way to deal with this is to create a List that will contains the column available to play.

```
List<Integer> columnsAvailable = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6));
```

Now it will look for something like this:

```
 void computerTurn(){
        int index = rnd.nextInt(columnsAvailable.size());
        int col = columnsAvailable.get(index);
        if(isAvailableCol(col)){
            placeInCol(computer, col);
        } else {
            columnsAvailable.remove(index);
            //get a new random column here.
        }
 }
```

Comment: @user3481879 call nextInt on your random object each time you want a new random number.

Answer (score 0):

The random number generated may repeat.That is the problem.So, you can save the generated random number  temporarily , and check it with the next random number , if they are same loop it again.This is a wide logic. You can use Collections.shuffle(); . Then , there will be no head ache regarding repeatation.